# Converting binary to decimals and characters

Tags: java

I want to convert binary to decimals and characters like this:

```
11010 --> 1101 + 0(parity bit) -->decimals= 11 --> char ";"
10101 --> 1010 + 1             -->decimals= 5  --> char "5"
.
.

public class stringek {

    String bitek = "1101010101001000001000001";
    String[] bits;
    String four;
    char par;
    int parity;
    String digits;
    int n = 0;
    int b;
    int kurens;
    int decimalis;
    int digit;

    public stringek() {
        this.kurens = 0;
        bits = new String[200];
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i += 5) {
            bits[n] = bitek.substring(i, i + 5);
            n++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int j = 0;
            four = bits[i].substring(j, j + 4);
            for (int p = 0; p < 4; ++p) {
                b = Integer.parseInt(four.substring(p));
                kurens += b;
            }
            par = bits[i].charAt(j+4);
            //System.out.print(par);
            parity = par-'0';
            decimalis = Integer.parseInt(four, 2);
            digit = decimalis + 48;
            if ((kurens + parity) % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Binarys: "+four+"-"+par+" = "+"'"+(char)digit+"'"+" Decimalis:"+decimalis+"  Parity <INVALID>  ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Binarys: "+four+"-"+par+" = "+"'"+(char)digit+"'"+" Decimalis:"+decimalis+"  Parity <VALID>  ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but my program results this:

```
Binarys: 1101-0 = '=' Decimalis:13  Parity <INVALID>  
Binarys: 1010-1 = ':' Decimalis:10  Parity <VALID>  
Binarys: 0010-0 = '2' Decimalis:2  Parity <INVALID>  
Binarys: 0001-0 = '1' Decimalis:1  Parity <INVALID>  
Binarys: 0000-1 = '0' Decimalis:0  Parity <VALID>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve? I have to say cause in my case all Parity is VALID, but I don't know why here some Parity is Invalid (I know cause the results from if give me this results, but I want to know how to resolve to be VALID when is valid and INVALID when is really invalid). thanks

Comment: I want...I want... **What have you done**?

Comment: The answer is: you'd use neither of the things you list. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Comment: I want my articles to write themselves, and my thesis to self-fabricate itself. Not doing too well on that front unfortunately :/ At any case here's something you might wanna take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit that into your question and explain why it doesn't work. I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String[] splitStringEvery(String s, int interval) {
    int arrayLength = (int) Math.ceil(((s.length() / (double)interval)));
    String[] result = new String[arrayLength];

    int j = 0;
    int lastIndex = result.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
        result[i] = s.substring(j, j + interval);
        j += interval;
    } //Add the last bit
    result[lastIndex] = s.substring(j);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @user3062456 it helps you my friend try it by passing interval value to 5

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use `String.split()` or a `StringTokenizer`

- Use a `for` loop that increments by 5, checking against length of your string
- Use `String.substring()` to extract the 5 character strings.

To compute the length of the target array you need, you'll need to divide your string length by 5. A Better idea is to use a `List<String>`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you use `split()` with a lookahead?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You believe you *could* (I'd have to play with it) ... but other than as a learning exercise I don't see why you *would*.

Comment: For that matter you *could* get the backing `char[]` and use `System.arraycopy()`, and create new Strings, or ... any number of other things :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Guava Libraries Splitter](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained) object, specifically the `fixedLength(...)` method which does ***exactly*** what you're trying to do.

```
Splitter splitter = Splitter.fixedLength(5);
Iterable<String> tokens= splitter.split(myVeryLongString);
```